# getting node-id in theme_uc_product_sell_price

Tags: drupal, templates, ubercart

For my ubercart drupal installation, I want to achieve conditional CSS formatting for list and sell price based on their values.

```
List price: --$120.00-- (stroked out)
Sell price: $100.00
```

I see that both are processed individually in `theme_uc_product_sell_price` and `theme_uc_product_price`. My questions where do I compare there values? As per my investigation I cannot override `uc_product_view` (which is master of all) in theme-template as it's not wrapped with theme(...).

If I can get current node ID in my template override `zen_uc_product_sell_price` I can still achieve this by loading node. Is this possible, how can I get node id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Required to create `node-product.tpl.php` in theme folder. Although, this requires to create your own template, it's pretty easy. All the required HTML code are available in following variable -

```
$node->content['body']["#value"];
$node->content['sell_price']["#value"];
$node->content['add_to_cart']["#value"];
$node->content['image']["#value"];
```

List price and sell price are available as `$node->list_price` and `$node->sell_price` to comapre.